# Как максимально сохранить авторскую пунктуацию?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> Ровно в полдень, каждый день, на холме высоко над городом – на другом
>   берегу Тибра, стреляет пушка.

А бы, конечно, всё повыбрасывала:

*Ровно в полдень каждый день на холме высоко над городом – на другом берегу Тибра стреляет пушка, -*

но теряется авторский ритм дыхания.

Можно ещё обособить другой берег Тибра - запятыми или тире...

Comment: Видимо, автор под впечатлением этого суперпунктуационного примера: _Однажды весною, в час небывало жаркого заката, в Москве, на Патриарших прудах, появились два гражданина._ Но у него поменяны местами "полдень" и "каждый день", поэтому второе не тянет на уточнение. Тире явно лишнее.

Comment: Саш, нарисуй варианты правки - в ответе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с сохранением "патриаршего" максимума знаков, нужно изменить порядок слов (для развития в сторону сужающих уточнений):

> Каждый день, ровно в полдень, на другом
>   берегу Тибра, на холме высоко над городом, стреляет пушка.